How to handle OwnsOne and OwnsMany entities in EF Core 8 with reflection
I want to add shadow properties to all entities.
What I did is to add shadow properties to the parent class (entity).
For this purpose I have written the following code in my DbContext:
var entityTypes = builder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
        .Where(e => typeof(Entity).IsAssignableFrom(e.ClrType)
                    && e.ClrType != typeof(Entity));

foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
{
    builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType)
            .Property<DateTime>("CreatedDate")
            .HasDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()");

    builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType)
            .Property<DateTime?>("UpdatedDate")
            .HasConversion(new ValueConverter<DateTime, DateTime>(v => v.ToUniversalTime(),
                    v => DateTime.SpecifyKind(v, DateTimeKind.Utc)))
            .ValueGeneratedOnUpdate();
}

But the problem is that it affects entities that are OwnsOne or OwnsMany:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'ContentCommandDbContext'. The
exception 'The entity type 'Comment' cannot be configured as non-owned
because it has already been configured as a owned. Use the nested
builder in OwnsOne or OwnsMany on the owner entity type builder to
further configure this type. If you want to override previous
configuration first remove the entity type from the model by calling
'Ignore'. See https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-owned for more information
and examples.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For
the different patterns supported at design time, see
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

To avoid this error, I need to identify the entities that are OwnsOne or OwnsMany and not put them in this code.I can do this using hard code, for example:
var entityTypes = builder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .Where(e => typeof(Entity).IsAssignableFrom(e.ClrType) && e.ClrType != typeof(Entity) && e.ClrType != typeof(Comment));

And it works fine, but it becomes problematic during development (we all know). Can this be done using reflection? I am new to reflection.

No reflection is needed, the information is provided by EF Core metadata API, in this case by the IReadOnlyEntityType.IsOwned method, e.g.
var entityTypes = builder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .Where(e => !e.IsOwned() && ...);


Thank you very much, my problem is completely solved. But I have a question, is there a way to add ShadowProperties to Owns types? Especially since I have separated their table in the database

@arman You are welcome. And yes, it is possible to add shadow properties to owned type, but you must use model API because you can get to the fluent model builder of the owned type (the one you get from OwnsOne or OwnsMany). For instance, the equivalent non fluent setup for CreatedDate would be var property = entityType.AddProperty("CreatedDate", typeof(DateTime)); property.SetColumnName(property.Name); property.SetDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()");, a bit more for the other ...

property = entityType.AddProperty("UpdatedDate", typeof(DateTime?)); property.SetColumnName(property.Name); property.SetValueConverter(new ...); property.ValueGenerated = ValueGenerated.OnUpdate;
